# sqlalchemy operator from variable

Tags: filter, sqlalchemy, operators

I try to pass an operator as variable in a filter query (sqlalchemy), but I don't know how do that:

I wrote this:

```
 while True:
        col_value = request.args.get(f'searchBuilder[criteria][{i}][value1]')
        if col_value is None:
            break
        col_name = request.args.get(f'searchBuilder[criteria][{i}][origData]')
        col_condition = request.args.get(f'searchBuilder[criteria][{i}][condition]')
        col_value = request.args.get(f'searchBuilder[criteria][{i}][value1]')
        if col_value:
            filters[col_name]['condition'] = col_condition
            filters[col_name]['value'] = col_value
        i += 1
    
    if filters:
        for k,v in filters.items():
            print(k,v['condition'],v['value'])
            query = query.filter(db.or_(getattr(eval(table), k).contains(v['value'])))
```

and I would like :

```
query = query.filter(db.or_(getattr(eval(table), k)**.v['condition']**(v['value'])))
```

this line:

```
print(k,v['condition'],v['value'])
```

gives:

```
name contains test
```

tried this:

```
 query = query.filter(db.or_(getattr(eval(table), k).v['condition'](v['value'])))
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Cms.name has an attribute 'v'
```

How set operator from a variable ?

Thx,